# Regex match two words

Tags: java, regex

I'm using Java regex and I need to match two words, but between these words can appear a space or another word, for e.g. "power energy", "power of energy", "power for energy". I have to obtain all variations of "power energy". Is it possible?

Further, I need to have something like "pow* ener*" to catch all the double words that start con pow and ener. For e.g "powers for energies".

Answer (score 3):

Use a simple [wild card](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2006/11/20/regular-expressions-part-xi-real-wildcards/#sr=g&m=o&cp=or&ct=-tmc&st=%28opu%20qspwjefe%29&ts=1384785667) between the two words in the patterns:

`"power(.*?)energy"` or just `"power.*energy"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/(?=power)(?=energy)/i
```

Answer (score 0):

The following

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\bpow\\w+)(.*?)(\\bener\\w+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Test powers test energies test.");
if(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Prints `powers test energies`. It should work with other variations that you posted. Obviously it will give you false positives if words start with `pow`, but that is what you seemed to want in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this pattern:

```
\\bpowers?\\s+(?:\\w+\\s+){0,2}energ(?:y|ies)\\b
```

note: if you want you can allows more than two words between "power" and "energy" increasing (or decreasing) the quantifier value inside curly brackets.

`\\b` is a word boundary to avoid having other letters (or digit or underscore) after or before a word.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to capture the words "power", "energy" and variations in groups, you can use:

```
(pow\S+\b).*(ener\S+\b)
```

In java:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(pow\\S+\\b).*(ener\\S+\\b)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("powers of energies");
if(matcher.find()) {
  int count = matcher.groupCount();
    for(int i=1;i<=count;i++){
      System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
    }
```

see http://ideone.com/eNY3br

Comment: Thanks, the last problem is that (pow\S+\b).*(ener\S+\b) matches also 2 o more words between pow and ener. I need only a space or almost 1 word.

Comment: you can try: `(pow\S+)\s{0,1}\w*\s{0,1}(ener\S+)`. This will match `power energies` and `power of energies` but not `power of my energies`

Comment: Thanks, it works but i have last question, into the document on which i m working i tried to write power like the last word of a row and energy like the first word of the next row. In this case it doesnt work. Do you have any idea? Thanks for all

Comment: @user3004412 sorry, I don't understand this... I suggest you post another question with your code so far and examples of input and expected output

Comment: i intend that in the page of example to match the words i tried to write "power" like the last word of the line and "energy" like the first word of the next line, it seems that the wrap doesnt work

Comment: @user3004412 I'm still not sure what you're trying to do... But newlines do work: here's an example using replaceAll- http://ideone.com/eNY3br